# Cardinality of a set in a field

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

If $$A = \bigg\{\sum_{i=0}^4a_i+b_i \ \big| \sum_{i=0}^4a_i+b_i = 0: a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{F}_{2^k}\bigg\}$$ where $\mathbb{F}_{2^k}$ is a field with $2^k$ elements for some positive integer $k$. I want to prove that cardinality of $A$ is $2^{9k}$. How to prove?

Comment: Pick $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3$. How many possibilities for that are there? How many choices for $b_4$ are there for each such choice you just made?

Comment: What Bob Jones said. The set $A$ is a subspace of a 10-dimensional vector space defined by a single non-trivial linear equation. From linear algebra we recall that $\dim A=$_____?

Comment: BTW Your set-builder notation is out of whack. Taken as written, the set $A$ has only a single element. This is because your notation says that the elements of the set $A$ are sums of the form $\sum_{i=0}^4(a_i+b_i)$ where the variables $a_i$ and $b_i$ are constrained to be solutions of $\sum_{i=0}^4(a_i+b_i)=0$. Therefore $0$ is the only element of $A$. I rather suspect that you wanted
$$A=\{(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,b_4)\in\Bbb{F}_{2^k}^{10}\mid\sum_{i=0}^4(a_i+b_i)=0\}.$$ Please clarify.